# Device emulator icon doesn't appear in cefsharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm using cefsharp.winform components.

I've added a function that on <kbd>F12</kbd> key press go and open the devtools
using this code:

```
m_Browser.ShowDevTools();
```

this works fine and I can see the devtools windows opens.

[image: devtools window]

but as you can see I'm missing the device emulator icon. I have all the pak files include devtools-resources.pak file.

Comment: There is a related CEF [issue](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1992/devtools-device-emulation-mode-missing-in) 
DevTools device emulation mode missing in 2623 and newer

Comment: It is possible to attach the chrome DevTools using remote debugging, may be an option. You'd have to do your own research on how to enable remote debugging